# Open Graph Actions IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Trying to post an OPEN GRAPH Facebook Action in my iPhone app.
Its returning an error on the object type. Though the object type is correct. Not sure what the problem is...

```
NSMutableDictionary  *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 

                                facebookToken, @"facebook_access_token",
                                @"photo", @"type",
                                @"IMG_URL_HERE", @"url",
                                @"Test Title", @"title",
                                @"IMG_URL_HERE", @"image",
                                @"Test Description", @"description",
                                nil];


[delegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath: @"me/APP_SHARED_NAME:shared" andParams:params andHttpMethod: @"POST" andDelegate: self];
```

Its returning with this error

```
Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x7fa78f0 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x7fa6b10 [0x1a0bb48]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
```

entries =>
    2 : {contents = "type"} = {contents = "Exception"}
    3 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: photo."}
    6 : {contents = "code"} = 1611072
}
}

Any one have ideas bout this???

Answer (score 0):

An *object* should refer to a publicly available URL with open graph tags. If you don't think that's the problem, please provide your *actual* code so we can be sure.